# Dropdown working in individual HTML page but not working in Angular component

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have written a simple code for a small drop down,

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group" _ngcontent-c9="" dropdown="">
    <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" _ngcontent-c9="">Action</button>
    <button class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" aria-expanded="false" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" _ngcontent-c9="">
        <span class="caret" _ngcontent-c9=""></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">abcd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">efgh</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

the angular component:
https://angular-kayp63.stackblitz.io
It works if I put it in an individual HTML page, but it doesn't work if I put it in the Angular component I created. Why?

Comment: can you share your code with https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: `but it doesn't work` what does that mean ?

Comment: I have added the stackblitz link

Comment: @Awais it means that its not dropping down.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqvq1i check it.
Where do you holding your bootstrap and jquery ? Maybe wrong imports

Comment: Then you should include these files in `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using libraries from outsite you should import them in the main index.html file. Propably you importing bootstrap and jquery in wrong place. I did a stackBlitz, and your code works correctly.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqvq1i

Answer (score 0):

It the issue with your `Import` you are not importing external files globally.

Set these inside `angular.json` file like below of your project

```
  "styles": [
              //some other styles
            "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css",
            ],
   "scripts": [
              //some other scripts
              "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js",
              "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            ],
```

> Don't forgot to re-run `ng-serve`